# Redefinition error when pulling GitHub

Tags: objective-c, git, github, git-pull

I've been using GitHub for a while for source control on a singular developer project but now I am trying to set it up across multiple machines.
Everything seems to be pushed correctly but when I clone it to my other Mac and try to run it I have a ton of Redefinition errors. Ex) "Redefinition of enumerator", "Property has a previous declaration" and so on.

Has anyone had any experience with this issue and what I can do to fix it.
I used a simple git clone on the target machine to retrieve it.

It is an iOS project in objective c.

Comment: This also happens if I simply copy and paste the project folder from one machine to another so I don't think it is necessarily a github pulling issue

Answer (score 0):

This probably has nothing to do with github. But it may be git.

It's possible that you did a 'git pull' and had a merge problem. If you run "git status", are some items red?  If so, look in those files for lines with "<<<<<" and ">>>>>". Those lines are telling you about a merge conflict. You need to fix the conflict and delete those lines, then `git add` the file and then commit + push the file back to github.

Alternately, you can do `git checkout <file>` to throw away any changes. (and maybe `git merge --abort`)